# Code splitting vue-i18n translation files in vue 3 (composition api)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I've been successfully using vue-i18n in my Vue 3 app but as the app grows the translation file is getting really big. And there are a small number of pages that aren't often requested that add a lot of text. I'd like to split those strings into a separate file and only load that file when the user goes to that page - you know, the way Vite is already doing wonderfully with my javascript.

Here's the relevant part of my setup in main.ts:

```
import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import { messages } from "@/i18n/messages";

export const i18n = createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    locale: "en",
    messages,
});

app.use(i18n)
```

And here's how I use it in my component:

```
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
const { t } = useI18n({ useScope: "global" });
```

Is there a way to create a separate translation file and pass it directly into that `useI18n` call so that it is only referenced on the pages that call that component?

Comment: You're probably looking for mergeLocaleMessage

Comment: Wow, there is pretty much zero documentation for that and zero examples. But thanks for the tip! I'll just experiment with it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much to Estus Flask for the hint. Here's the entire file of what I did.

```
// dashboard-messages contains the same format as my regular messages file.
import {messages} from "@/i18n/dashboard-messages"
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

export function addDashboardMessages() {
    // the locale is already set, so I can just see what it is
    const l = useI18n().locale
    const locale = l.value
    // Just target in the messages for one locale
    const localeMessages = messages[locale]
    useI18n().mergeLocaleMessage(locale, localeMessages)
}
```

I hope this helps someone else!